# Crash when editing profile on data explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer, status-completed

I just tried to update my profile on SEDE, but got a crash (the ASP.Net yellow screen of death) when I clicked save.

Does the "about me" section support markdown (like the other SOFU sites), as I was trying to edit that info and was including markdown in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (AboutMe="...Server. <br/> <br/> My (lo...").
```

I'll get it sorted.

Comment: Ta. "I'll get it sorted" - does that mean support for markdown in the about box?

Comment: I'll make sure its aligned with the SO profile editor

Comment: Its now inline with the SO profile editor, markdown and some html allowed

Comment: This is an old post, but this happened to me just now: I logged in using myopenid, noticed that my profile showed up as "hmemcpy1". When I clicked "Edit" to try and remove the "1", upon saving I got a YSOD.